# Repeating local notification is triggered immediately -- how to defer?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios10

My goal is to set a notification that will occur N seconds in the future for the first time, and then repeat every N seconds.

However, creating a repeating notification seems to trigger the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` immediately.

App delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    return true
}

func startRequest() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.body = bodyText
    content.categoryIdentifier = categoryIdentifier
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
    trigger.nextTriggerDate()
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // This callback received right after the request is made
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}
```

I can work around this by creating a non-repeating notification and then starting repeating notifications when it expires. However, I was hoping there was some way to specify a first trigger date -- if memory serves right, the old notification API had this ability, and perhaps I am misunderstanding this new API

Thanks!

Comment: It might be a bug. I've seen this question asked before.

Comment: Here's an idea. Try a much bigger interval, like 600. Does it fire immediately now?

Comment: @matt it still fires with very large intervals

Comment: Another idea: Are you testing on a device?

Comment: No, on an emulator. I will try testing on a device in a few weeks, but how do you think it might be related to the issue I'm seeing?

Comment: The emulator is only an emulator. There are _lots_ of differences between how it behaves and how the device behaves, especially in regard to things the runtime is supposed to do (or not do) in the background, so how do we know _a priori_ that this is not one of them?

Comment: I am experiencing this as well, on a device.  Feels like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you aren't setting the title on the `UNMutableNotificationContent()`.

```Swift
content.title = "Title goes Here"
```

Also, to see if there is an error adding the request, you can add the following code.

```
center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
   if let theError = error {
     // Handle any errors
   }
}
```

I got this from Apple's docs - https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unmutablenotificationcontent

Comment: I tried setting a title -- did not seem to affect anything. There also doesn't seem to be an error occurring.