# Scheduling repeating local notification in the future

Tags: ios, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationtrigger

Is it possible to schedule a repeating local notification in the future?  I'm trying to set up a repeating notification every 10 min starting in 30 min for example. (iOS 11 Swift)

I've tried using `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` but I'm not sure how to set when it should start. From what I've found the trigger fires as soon as it's added it to `UNUserNotificationCenter`.

Since the user might close the app I don't think I can first create a single notification then wait until that triggers to set up a repeating one.

I've looked at this: [Repeating local notification is triggered immediately -- how to defer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768342/repeating-local-notification-is-triggered-immediately-how-to-defer)
And this: [iOS 11- User local notification which repeat every x minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094716/ios-11-user-local-notification-which-repeat-every-x-minutes)
And this: [UserNotification in 3 days then repeat every day/hour - iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380783/usernotification-in-3-days-then-repeat-every-day-hour-ios-10)

So no one seems to have figured it out.

(I don't want it to repeat every day or weekly or on a specific day.)

Comment: _"But I'm looking for local notifications."_ All the questions you linked **are** local notifications.

Comment: What you are looking for does not seem to be possible with the new notification APIs; you cannot combine a calendar trigger with an interval trigger.  You could use the deprecated APIs where this is possible; although deprecated they will still work.

Comment: Your notification center delegate gets some execution time when the user interacts with a notification, even if it's to dismiss. Can you use that, when the user hits the first one, to schedule the rest? They could ignore or miss it, of course.

Comment: @JoshCaswell For the type of app I'm building the user won't want to interact with the notification. Thanks for the workaround idea though!